# efi shell command and register R/W

Tags: cpu-registers, uefi

I got a basic question of `efi mm command`.
I need to control a controller (MAC) inside a SOC, and let it generate MDIO traffic to external PHY chip, to read its ID.
The instruction told me to do the following under efi shell

Shell> `mm xxxxxxx yyyyyyy -w 4 -MEM -n`

Shell> `mm xxxxxxx -w 4 -MEM -n`

I'm wondering what's the mm command do?
Looks like it write to `xxxxxx` register the `yyyyyy` data, and then "mm" this register again?
Not sure why.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mm` command is explained in the [UEFI Shell Specification](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Shell_2_2.pdf):

`mm address [value] [-w 1|2|4|8] [-MEM | -PMEM | -MMIO | -IO | -PCI | -PCIE] [-
n]`

The description states "If value is specified, which should be typed in hex format, this command will write this value to specified address. Otherwise when this command is executed, the current contents of address are displayed.".

So your first command writes the 32-bit value `yyyyyyy` to address `xxxxxxx`, and the second command reads a 32-bit value from address `xxxxxxx` - presumably to verify that the write took effect.

Comment: Thanks for the spec.

Comment: I read the register definition, looks like it's a function that user first write the register value into the register address, and then we can read data back from the same register, just like the BAR register in PCIe configuration space....:)

Answer (score 0):

Sample startup.nsh

```
    #Sample startup.nsh
    
    @echo -off
    # Clear screen
    cls
    
    # Print date and time
    date
    time
    
    # Set special register of the CPU (Intel Denverton C3758R)
    # EFI Shell style is "mm fe000018 29C0202C -w 4 -MEM -n"
    # (more detail usage, Use "help mm")
    # but not implement in startup.nsh with error "Invalid data width"
    
    # No need option "-n" for Non-interactive write
    mm fe000018 4 :29C0002C
    
    # Non-interactive read
    mm fe000018 4 -n
    mm e00fa0a4 4 -n
    
    # System shutdown
    reset -s
```